# how to use text tag in MVC 3 razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to use regex on the views i have in MVC 3 page. how i can use

when i wrap them with text tag they not work ex:

```
<text> var pattern = @fjkfdkl</text>
```

i  not want to put @@ instead of @ on every pattern. well what is the way and rule for using text tag in MVC

Comment: @sLaks i do a litle mistake i talking about text tag in mvc

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to escape the regex pattern using @ and razor is confused by this.  I think you'll need to use the double @@ so razor engine isn't confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you wrap something in a text tag your are saying to Razor that "this is text" not code. If you want code you can then do a code block like:

```
<text>@{ var pattern = fjkfdkl; }</text>
```

If you are doing this in some sort of loop you can just continue writing your code:

```
foreach(var o in listOfObjects) {
  var pattern = fjkfdkl;
}
```

In the above example razor knows whats code and what is not. You can then expand on the above example if you want to put markup in the loop:

```
foreach(var o in listOfObjects) {
  var pattern = fjkfdkl;
  <text>
    Hello World!
  </text>
}
```

or

```
foreach(var o in listOfObjects) {
  var pattern = fjkfdkl;
  <p>
    Hello World.
  <p>
}
```

You only really need to use the `<text></text>` tags inside of loops where you don't have any html tags.

Razor is smart enough so when you open your tag inside a loop e.g. `<p>` it know until that tag is closed then its in markup. When it is closed it will then look for a `}` for the closing of a loop (or another html tag).