# <text> tag in _LoginPartial.cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

The _LoginPartial.cshtml file created by the MVC 4 template contains a `<text>` tag, like this:

```
<text>
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
</text>
```

As far as I can tell, `<text>` is not a recognized tag, so why did the folks who created this code use that tag?

Comment: That is a razor tag as you can see if you Googled it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969065/how-to-use-text-tag-in-mvc-3-razor

Comment: Its Razor snippet for a text block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the commenters to the OP said, `<text>` is special Razor syntax to denote text.  As [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) explains, this syntax can be used in lieu of the `@:` syntax.